# Regex to replace in json string

Tags: java, json, regex

Is there a regex expression I can use to find all the numbers in JSON string and replace them within double quotes?

For example in the below JSON string, I want to replace the Id and Phone values with double quotes.

```
String jsonString = " [ 
{ 
   "FirstName": "abc",  
   "Email" : "a@a.com",
   "Id" : 1,
   "Phone" : 1234567890,
   "Date": "2 May 2016 23:59:59"

}, 
{  
   "FirstName": "xyz",  
   "Email" : "b@b.com",
   "Id" : 2,
   "Phone" : 9876543210,
   "Date": "3 May 2016 23:59:59" 

} 
] ";
```

I want to get the following output:

```
[ 
    { 
       "FirstName":"abc",  
       "Email" : "a@a.com",
       "Id" : "1",
       "Phone" : "1234567890",
       "Date": "2 May 2016 23:59:59"

    }, 
    {  
       "FirstName":"xyz",  
       "Email" : "b@b.com",
       "Id" : "2",
       "Phone" : "9876543210",
       "Date": "3 May 2016 23:59:59"  

    } 
    ]
```

I tried line below but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
 jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("=[ ]*([\\d]+)", "= \"$1\"");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing multiple things wrong.

- Your regex searches for matches starting with a `=` instead of `:`
- To capture white(space) use `\s`

Here is your correct regex: https://regex101.com/r/sRDXMP/2/

And here is your fixed code:  `jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(":\\s([\\d]+)", ": \"$1\"");`

Comment: Escaping the backslash itself is not an error, thats Java syntax (unfortunately)

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath thanks, updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `=` in your regular expression by `:`
Also, you should use the whitespace selector instead of `[ ]`.

`jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(":\\s*(\\d+)", ": \"$1\"");`

Comment: I also have a date object. so the : should not be replaced. i have edited my post again.

Comment: Then you just need to expect a comma or a right curly bracket after your digits: `":\\s*(\\d+)\s*[,}]"`